# How to display image after upload in php?

Tags: php, image

after uploading the image to a folder. how to display the image..

its my upload.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000000000000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br>";

$image=$_FILES["file"]["name"]; /* Displaying Image*/
      $img="upload/".$image;
      echo '<img src= "upload/".$img>'; 

      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

the image is uploading fine. but the image is not displaying. a small box only showing.

this part not working...

```
/* Displaying Image*/
       $image=$_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
              $img="upload/".$image;
              echo '<img src= "upload/".$img>';
```

how to display the image after upload success?

Comment: Try `"<img src=\"upload/$img\">"`

Comment: What is the html source output for the `echo '<img src= "upload/".$img>';`? and does the url of the `src` attribute accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($imgPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've already put "upload" in $img

```
$img="upload/".$image;
```

You don't need to put it in src anymore

```
echo '<img src= "'.$img.'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and its working finely just need to change the line

```
echo'<img src= "upload/".$img>';
```

to

```
echo'<img src="'.$img.'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

`echo '<img src="upload/'.$img.'"/>';`

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up some quotes. It should be :

```
$image = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
$img = "upload/".$image;
echo "<img src=\"upload/$img\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put $img in quotations. When you do it the output is simply $img, not upload/...

echo `< img src=" ' ,$img ,' ">;`

Answer (score 0):

We have to Put **`enctype = "multipart/form-data"`** inside the form

> ```
>   <html>
>   <body>
>   <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
>      <input type = "file" name = "image" />
>      <input type = "submit"/>
>       
>      <ul>
>         <li>Sent file:  echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  
>         <li>File size:  echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  
>         <li>File type:  echo $_FILES['image']['type'] 
>         <li><img src=" echo 'images/'.$file_name; "> 
>      </ul>
>       
>   </form>
>       </body> </html>
> ```

We Have

> ```
>   //file_upload.php
>
>   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){$errors= array();
>
>   $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
>
>   $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
>
>   $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
>
>   $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
>
>   $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
>   
>   $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
>   
>   if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
>      $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
>   }
>   
>   if($file_size > 2097152) {
>      $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
>   }
>   
>   if(empty($errors)==true) {
>      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
>      echo "Success";
>   }else{
>      print_r($errors);
>   }    } ?>
> ```

Answer (score -3):

Just do this

```
echo '<img src="upload/'.$file_name.' "/>
```

We have to take the `$file_name` variable because..
`""` (double quotes) can only return text in the variable - it cannot return binary number to show image!