# PHP reading uploaded file after post

Tags: php

PHP reading uploaded file content issue

I upload a txt file, and I did the following

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

The output was

```
Array ( [up_file] => Array ( [name] => upload.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbyrYwN [error] => 0 [size] => 26 ) )
```

When I did the following

```
$tmp_file_path = strtolower($_FILES['up_file']['tmp_name']); //rename file
$file_content = file_get_contents($tmp_file_path);
```

The   $tmp_file_path return me  /tmp/phpbyrYwN 
but $file_content return nothing, I went to root via ssh and check /tmp but did not see any file by the name /tmp/phpbyrYwN , what should I do to resolve this.

Should I state a default directory for uploaded file in any part of the code or ?

Comment: by calling strtolower function you can't rename file!

try this code without calling strtolower function

Comment: I tried without strtolower, same issue happen, the file get contents return nothing

Comment: You're trying to get the contents of a temp file. See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/21703154/ - I would give an "answer", but you haven't posted full code, so it would only be guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your file system seem to be case-sensitive,

and you try to read the lower-cased file name.

try it without the `strtolower`:

```
<?php
$tmp_file_path = $_FILES['up_file']['tmp_name']; 
$file_content = file_get_contents($tmp_file_path);
```